# Please tell me what is error in this javascript code

Tags: asp.net, javascript, variables

i have written following code to access public variable of asp.net onclick event on button
but its not giving me desired output.. please check it:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="txtdisplay" ID="Button1"
 Text="Browse all jobs in area" 
OnClientClick="return navigateURL('index.aspx?c=<%=cityid %>')" />
```

Comment: You haven't really given enough information to answer your question directly.  What's navigateURL() doing?  What's in the cityid field, and what output do you want to have?

Comment: navigateURL is javascript function which is taking string parameter

Comment: cityid field is of type integer at serverside as a public variable

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inline anything for server controls. You have to do it in the code behind.

This:

```
"return navigateURL('index.aspx?c=<%=cityid %>')"
```

Should Be This:

```
Button1.OnClientClick = "return navigateURL('index.aspx?c=" + city + ")";
```